# How to improve React Native Touchable experience?

Tags: react-native

I have many touchable Items, made them using TouchableOpacity but the problem is in app all the buttons going fade out don't look that attractive I used with native feedback it looks good in android but dumb in ios, is there any way I can make a vibration of ms without going to all the buttons and using Vibration api from react native?

Comment: What are you asking exactly? You mention TouchableOpacity and TouchableNativeFeedback and vibration. 
What exactly do you want to happen when the view is pressed?

Answer (score 0):

What I did is, created a button component and inside I used vibration api,
If you are lazy enough to not go to each screen and replace it i create a component called TouchableOpacity and remove import from react native and add your custom touchableOpacity's link

Moreover there is a library called react native ripple it gives a button that releases ripple on press check it out